# Cubic equation in the Hessian polynomial

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, maxima-minima, cubics, hessian-matrix

I am stuck in solving the cubic equation which does arise from the calculation of the characteristic polynomial of a Hessian matrix.

Starting from the beginning, the problem is a max-min problem:

$$f(x, y, z) = yz + x^2y + x^2 + y^2 - z^2$$

$$\nabla f(x, y, z) = (2xy + 2x, z + x^2 + 2y, y - 2z)$$

Solutions of $\nabla f = 0$ are the points

$$P = (0, 0, 0)$$
$$Q = \left(\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}, -1, -\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$
$$K = \left(-\sqrt{\dfrac{5}{2}}, -1, -\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$$

The general Hessian reads

$$
H = \begin{pmatrix}
2y + 2 & 2x & 0 \\
2x & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The point P is a saddle point, since the eigenvalues are both positive and negative.

But when I am going to calculate the characteristic polynomial in $P$ and or $K$ I obtain, for example in $P$, the equation

$$-\lambda^3 + 15\lambda + 20 = 0$$

How can I solve this?

Comment: Use Sylvester's criterion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/199596/sylvesters-criterion-and-function-extrema

Answer (score 2):

You just face a depressed cubic equation.

Following the steps given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation), there three real roots since $\Delta=2700$. So, use the trigonometric method described in the linked page
$$\lambda_k=2 \sqrt{5} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  k}{3}-\frac{1}{3} \cos
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}\right)\right) \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=0,1,2$$